# How to access static member on WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, static

i want to access static member which is located in WCF service.

```
public class PDFService : IPDFService
{
 public string CreatePDF()
  { //some code      
  }

private static event EventHandler MyPrivateEvent;
public static event EventHandler MyEvent 
 {
   add { MyPrivateEvent += value; } 
   remove { MyPrivateEvent -= value; } 
 }
}
```

I tried to access this MyEvent member from a Windows Store app, but it doesnt work.

I want to accomplish something like this (similar to example from msdn):

```
    PDFServiceClient proxy = new PDFServiceClient();        
 //Wire the proxy to a completed handler to allow the async operation to be handled                     
    proxy.MyEvent += new EventHandler<CreatePDFCompletedEventArgs>(
        proxy_CreatePDFCompleted);
 //Call the service asynchronously
    await proxy.CreatePDFAsync();
```

Comment: It wont work?? A bit more information please.

Comment: Is the second snippet your own code or is it taken from MSDN? If so, it looks like the types are wrong, your class is `PDFService` but your example shows a `PDFServiceClient`

Comment: PDFService.PDFServiceClient() (namespace is included  above this code). I said it doesn't work, meaning it can not access MyEvent from WCF class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events are not exposed to the consumer of a WCF service. Neither are static members at all. The only things exposed are the operations in the service contracts, and any types used by those operations.

Comment: But  then how could this example work? proxy.GetCustomerCompleted can be nothing but an event, or am I wrong?      http://dotnetcodeplex.blogspot.com/2009/11/consuming-wcf-services-in-silverlight-3.html

Comment: That is an event that is part of the proxy object. It has nothing to do with the implementation of the server. Silverlight only handles asynchronous operations, so a proxy for Silverlight must have such events to signal when the operation completes.